# Shortest algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Suppose I write an algorithm to perform a computation but I get the intuition that my algorithm is a bit too long, however, it is not immediately obvious to me what a shorter algorithm might be. Is there a way for me to prove the (non-)existence of a shorter algorithm that performs that task - *without* necessarily having to write out the shorter algorithm (if it exists)?

Comment: Determining whether a given algorithm is shortest is probably undecidable, and so not all instances of shortest algorithms can be proved so.

Comment: It is quite frequent that an efficient program be longer that its inefficient counterpart, even though they give identical outputs. Being short is not an interesting property, unless you add extra constraints.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What if I were to rewrite the question with “most efficient” instead of “shortest”? Then can I prove (non-)existence of a most efficient algorithm (without constructing it)?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Do you know where I could look to find a proof of that and/or a proof of a shortest algorithm for some class of algorithms?

Comment: Depending on how you define "efficient" you might be able to prove that your algorithm is optimal, or asymptotically optimal. How do so depends on the algorithm and the problem at hand.

Comment: In general, a most efficient algorithm does not exist. Because it can easily fail to be the fastest on all inputs. This criterion is worse.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is not asymptotically solved when we have not found the tight bound, i.e. the lower bound being equal to the upper bound. It is possible to solve this asymptotically for most algorithm, but absolute shortest algorithm is undecidable according to Rice's theorem.

Rice's theorem states that all non-trivial semantic properties of programs are undecidable. A semantic property is one about the program's behavior (for instance, does the program terminate for all inputs), unlike a syntactic property (for instance, does the program contain an if-then-else statement). A property is non-trivial if it is neither true for every program, nor false for every program.